# WebApi2 External Login using Facebook in Windows phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I have been trying to follow this post `http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/?p=1071` to do external login via facebook by using the webbrowser control in Windows phone. But i can't get to get it working. The Web browser after authenticating on Facebook redirects back to `/api/ExternalLogin` and stays there with a blank screen (btw it's 200 OK). According to the post i am supposed to be redirected back to the homepage with a bearer token.

Is there somewhere i need to change to get the bearer token?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I am adding this anyway since I was struggling with this for a long time.  As the original post says you dont have to use a browser.  You can do it using code only.  Have a  look at the following

http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

This works fine.  The example itself did not work on my machine for some reason, but the concepts worked just fine and you need to modify the client (phone) code accordingly.